# The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have 2 apps, 1 for dashboard (VueJS) and 1 for api (Laravel)...

In my laravel, I have an api function that uploads an image to my s3 bucket :

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['uploadimage']]);
        $this->middleware('cors');
    }
   
    public function uploadimage(Request $request) {
        $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
        $disk->put($request->path.'/'.$request->file_name, base64_decode($request->file));
    } 
}
```

and I called this function in my VueJS App by:

```
uploadImage(ext) {
    const d = new Date();
    const self = this;
    const f = new URLSearchParams();
    f.append('user_id', localStorage.getItem('id'))
    f.append('file_name', 'ProfilePicture-'+d.getTime()+'-'+localStorage.getItem('id')+'.'+ext);
    f.append('path', 'public/images');
    f.append('file', this.image_crop[0].replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, ''));
    this.axios.post('uploadimage'), f, {
            headers: ''
        }).then(response => {
            const status = response.data.status;
            if (status == 1) {
                Toast._success(self, 'Success!', 'You have successfully updated your profile picture.');
            } else {
                if (status == 0) {
                    Toast._error(self, 'Oops!', 'Something went wrong. Please try again later.');
                }
            }
            console.log('res ', response);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('err ', err);
        })
    }
```

This works well on my local development environment with local db(xampp)..

but when I deploy the `Laravel and VueJS App` in my AWS ec2 ubuntu(apache) with RDS mysql db and upload an image, I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentException: The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameters: Bucket in file /var/www/api.myapp.com/public_html/myapp_be/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/InputValidationMiddleware.php
```

Btw, `api.myapp.com` is where the `Laravel` located.

I'm new to `Laravel` and `AWS` and I just can't find anything related to this problem.
Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved the issue, it was just that I forgot to populate the `s3` properties in the `filesystems.php`.

To resolve the issue, follow the steps:

**1.** Go to `filesystems.php`
**2.** Find the `disk` array and inside it is the `s3` array
**3.** In the `s3` array, fill the following properties with the values the same in the `.env`:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            ...
        ],

        'public' => [
            ...
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'Same with the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID value in the .env file'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', 'Same with the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID value in the .env file'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'Same with the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION value in the .env file'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET', 'Your s3 bucket'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'), //You can keep this as is
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'), //You can keep this as is
        ],

    ],
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: I run on the issue but this did not work for me.

Comment: Don't forget to clear your configuration cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 3):

I follow the first answer and I just change the default value in s3 to '' like this:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', ''),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', ''),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', ''),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET', ''),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL', ''),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT')
        ],
```

and run `php artisan config:cache`

You can check your env variable:

```
use Config
.....
.....
dd(Config::get('filesystems'));
.....
.....
```

and you can use this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->push($fileName, file_get_contents($request->file));
```

Comment: This also works if you're doing a phpunit test or github actions so +1 for that. My problem was near exact similar but its on fetching: `The GetObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error this morning (everything was still working the day before). After searching on Google, I found this question on Stackoverflow (lol).

It took about 30 minutes, I found that the problem is I reinstalled my project on a new computer and forgot to update the .env file with the config info for AWS S3.

So just check the .env file and make sure you have updated the following information:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_URL=
```

Comment: Btw, I solved this issue. Tho I had everything in the `.env` file set up.
In the `filesystem.php`, I forgot to fill the necessary keys in the  `s3` array from the `disk` array

Comment: Don't forget to clear your configuration cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

For me it turns out my .env was not being read. I was able to solve it by placing the values directly in the filesystems.php. It worked...

```
 's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'KJHKHKJHKJHKJ',
            'secret' => 'Khkgjhbjhjkgg87576',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'bucket' => 'nameofbucket',
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        ],
```

Comment: This really isn't recommended, since your keys will be visible in your git repository. They should instead be kept untracked in a .gitignore'd .env file.

What was likely going on is that your .env was cached, which can be cleared (along with anything else cached) by `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues found out i had no credentials on .env file.
Make sure to fill env with AWS S3 Credentials and make sure to update on "s3" Array at config/filesystems.php.

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],
```

Above code credentials should match this in your env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_URL =
```